# Adding items in hashMap inside actionListener

Tags: java, swing, hashmap

I'm trying to make a simple GUI program that can be used to make multiple choices inside a game. I understand that I have to take all the questions, their choices, and the right answer as well. My problem is that when I try to collect the right answers in the hashmap, I get only the last true answer and its duplicated within the hashmap. In addition, I received a problem when collecting choices and solved the issue with an unusual for-loop, but unfortunately I couldn't do that with answers.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class ExamFrame extends JFrame {

    private ExamPanel examPanel;
    private static int count = 1;
    static HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> choicesMap = new HashMap<>();
    static ArrayList<String> choicesList = new ArrayList<>();
    static HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<String>> truesMap = new HashMap<>();
    static ArrayList<String> truesList = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> prompts = new ArrayList<>();

    public ExamFrame() {
        super("Making exam");
        examPanel = new ExamPanel();
        setContentPane(examPanel);
        setSize(700,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class ExamPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
        private JLabel quLabel;
        private JTextField questionField;
        private ArrayList<JCheckBox> jCheckBoxes;
        private ArrayList<JTextField> respnsesFields;
        private JButton suivant,terminer;
        private JPanel centerPanel;

        public ExamPanel() {
            centerPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
            suivant = new JButton("next");
            suivant.addActionListener(this);
            terminer = new JButton("Finish");
            terminer.setEnabled(false);
            terminer.addActionListener(this);
            layoutComponents();
        }

        public void layoutComponents() {
            setBackground(Color.green);
            setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel prince = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gc.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
            prince.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
            gc.gridy = 0;
            gc.weightx = 1;
            gc.weighty = 0.1;
            gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gc.gridx = 0;
            quLabel = new JLabel("Question: ");
            prince.add(quLabel,gc);
            gc.gridx = 1;
            gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            questionField = new JTextField(45);
            prince.add(questionField, gc);
            jCheckBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
            respnsesFields = new ArrayList<>();

            for (int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
                JCheckBox jCheckBox= new JCheckBox("Reponse "+(j+1));
                jCheckBoxes.add(jCheckBox);
                gc.gridy++;
                gc.weightx = 1;
                gc.weighty = 0.1;
                gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
                gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
                gc.gridx=0;
                prince.add(jCheckBox,gc);
                JTextField jTextField = new JTextField(40);
                respnsesFields.add(jTextField);
                gc.gridx=1;
                gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
                gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
                prince.add(jTextField,gc);
            }
            gc.gridy++;
            gc.weightx = 1;
            gc.weighty = 0.1;
            gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 5);
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_END;
            gc.gridx=0;
            prince.add(suivant,gc);
            gc.gridx=1;
            gc.insets = new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0);
            gc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.LINE_START;
            prince.add(terminer,gc);
            centerPanel.add(prince,BorderLayout.CENTER);
            add(centerPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        suivant.setEnabled(false);
        if (count<=3) { //3 == Number of questions
            suivant.setEnabled(true);
            if (e.getSource() == suivant) {
                String prompt = questionField.getText();
                prompts.add(prompt);
                ExamPanel.this.setVisible(false);
                ExamFrame.this.setContentPane(new ExamPanel());
                for (int i=0;i<2;i++) { //2 == Number of choices
                    choicesList.add(respnsesFields.get(i).getText());
                }
                for (int i=0;i<2;i++) {
                    if (jCheckBoxes.get(i).isSelected()) {
                        truesList.add(respnsesFields.get(i).getText());
                    }
                }
                truesMap.put(count,truesList);
                truesList.clear();
                count++;
            }
        }
        else {
            terminer.setEnabled(true);
            questionField.setEnabled(false);
            for (JTextField jTextField:respnsesFields) {
                jTextField.setEnabled(false);
            }
            suivant.setEnabled(false);
            if (e.getSource() == terminer) {
                System.out.println(choicesList);
                for (int i=0;i<3;i++) {
                    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int j=(i*2);j<(i+1)*2;j++) {
                        arrayList.add(choicesList.get(j));
                    }
                    choicesMap.put(i,arrayList);
                }
                System.out.println(choicesMap);
                System.out.println(truesMap);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ExamFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a *new* ArrayList for each distinct item placed into the Map. Your program has only one truesList ArrayList instance that all Map items share. Inside of the ActionListener's actionPerformed method, create the new ArrayList (if one is needed -- if you're creating a new item to put into the Map), and place it into the Map along with the Integer key.

e.g.,

```
if (e.getSource() == suivant) {
    truesList = new ArrayList<>(); // !!  ADDED *****
    String prompt = questionField.getText();
    prompts.add(prompt);
    ExamPanel.this.setVisible(false);
    ExamFrame.this.setContentPane(new ExamPanel());
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) { // 2 == Number of choices
        choicesList.add(respnsesFields.get(i).getText());
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        if (jCheckBoxes.get(i).isSelected()) {
            truesList.add(respnsesFields.get(i).getText());
        }
    }
    truesMap.put(count, truesList);
    // !! truesList.clear();  // !! REMOVED ****
    count++;
}
```

Side note: if you're using a `Map<Integer, List<String>>`, and the Integer key String is monotonically increasing as yours is, why use a Map at all? Why not simply use nested lists?

```
List<List<String>> truesList = new ArrayList<>();
```

The index of the outside list will be the same as the Integer key for the HashMap.

Comment: you are a life saver man thank you so i've lost 4 hours with this simple issue

Comment: @blabla Do mark this as the correct answer if it's what you needed.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels because after that i will take all the information and save it in a database so i will need that key in the future

Comment: @blabla: but the ArrayList index would work just as well. Regardless, as long as it works and is easy to debug, that's what matters.